# Load Image using Glide 4 from FTP

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I am trying to load an image using [GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). The URL is ftp://122.180.85.249/profilePic/myFile-1578746143852.jpg

But it is failed to load. I am using below mentioned code:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(path).into(imgView)
```

Also tried:

```
Glide.with(mContext)asBitmap().load(path).into(imgView)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Also, I have seen this [Github way](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2991#issuecomment-497220796) which is using custom ModelLoader which I cannot use according to the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Glide doesn't directly support ftp urls out of the box. You must adjust the project structure to use ModelLoader to retrieve ftp streams.